# How to handle multiple requests within each concrete command in command design pattern?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, factory-pattern, command-pattern

I want to use command pattern in one of my projects where I have to make multiple REST calls. I have encapsulated web method calls according to the module it belongs to. Like XYZDataManager contains all web method calls related to XYZ module.

Having said that, how is Command pattern going to fit in here? I don't want to make command classes for every single web method call. I want to preserve encapsulation I mentioned above.

One thought that came to my mind is making some enum like RequestType, inside every concrete Command class. And then we have execute(RequestType) method in Command interface. Each concrete command implements execute(RequestType) accordingly and call inner methods as decided by RequestType param.

Am I doing right? Or there can be a better way? Or using Command Pattern here is simply a waste altogether?

Is leaving complete request creation (including RequestType and which concrete command to use) to consumer code a good idea? Or should it be moved to a Factory method that abstracts this from consumer code?

Comment: Can you clarify what problem you're trying to solve here? Might the Mediator pattern be more suitable if you're looking for a way to tie the things that do with what must be done?

Comment: I just want  a separation between invoker and receiver of commands so that  adding new commands does not result in modification of invoker.

Comment: Then it sounds like the Mediator pattern is for you. This (http://codeopinion.com/organize-by-feature/) series of blog posts might prove useful?

Answer (score 1):

The command pattern is used to separate the generation / invocation of a command from its execution. It is not appropriate in the context of a REST server. The use of a REST protocol makes the command pattern superfluous: the REST protocol itself separates invocation from execution.

Typical places where the command pattern is used are in multi-threading and in monolithic applications with GUI's. It is not suitable for multi-processing. REST can be used in multi-processing environments.

Answer (score 1):

I have used REST in a java web service and used command pattern in that.
In my usage , I had one Resource class which exposes all the REST endpoints(GET,POST,PUT,DELETE )  . The methods for these endpoints called different commands depending on usages.

eg : A GET method called GetUserDataCommand class ... .

So the command pattern was used to encapsulate the actions but there was only one resource class(e.g. UserResource) per endpoint (e.g. /user) .